# Android: FileProvider IllegalArgumentException Failed to find configured root that contains

Tags: android

I am trying to use `FileProvider` to open the image in the gallery by using intent. But I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com.example.diksha.chatapplication/app_photos/diksha.jpg
```

I tried many solutions provided in other similar questions but nothing really worked for me.

provider_path.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<provider
       android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider
       android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
       android:exported="false"
       android:grantUriPermissions="true">
       <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

Java Code

```java
private Uri saveImage(Bitmap image){
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getContext().getApplicationContext());
        File directory = cw.getDir("photos", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        File path = new File(directory, "diksha.jpg");
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        try{
            out = new FileOutputStream(path);
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try {
                out.close();
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(),getContext().getPackageName() + ".fileprovider", path);
    }
```

MessageAdapter

```java
public void onClick(View view) {
         Intent intent = new Intent();
         intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
         intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
         intent.setDataAndType(message.getmImage(), "image/*");
         mContext.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getContext().getApplicationContext());
File directory = cw.getDir("photos", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

with:

```
File directory = new File(getFilesDir(), "photos");
```

`FileProvider` does not serve from arbitrary directories you create with `getDir()`. It will serve from `getFilesDir()` and subdirectories off of it, though.

And you very rarely should be creating a `ContextWrapper` instance.